# How can I split loop into 2 different div and pass 3 posts per div and repeat it untill end

Tags: wordpress, loops

Suppose I have 2 HTML div named div1 and div2. I wanted to pass the 1st,2nd,3rd post into div1 and 4th,5th,6th post in div2. and next 3 will go in div1 and next 3 will go in div2 and this will continue until the end

```html
 <div class="sitecontainer">
  
  <div class="tips-and-news-wrap left-containrer">

   <ul class="tips-and-news-posts">

    <li>1st Post</li>
    <li>2nd Post</li>
    <li>3rd one</li>
 
   </ul>

  </div>
     
  <div class="tips-and-news-wrap right-conatiner">

    <ul class="tips-and-news-posts">

     <li>4th post</li>
     <li>5th post</li>
     <li>6th post</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

 </div
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="sitecontainer">

      <div class="tips-and-news-wrap left-containrer">

        <ul class="tips-and-news-posts">

           <?php 

           if ( have_posts() ) {

             while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 

               <li><?php the_title();</li> //this will display the 1st post to 9th post

             } // end while

           } // end if

          ?>

        </ul>

      </div>

   </div>
```

If you need to achieve the layout below. You need to do it in CSS. There's a lot of ways to do this. I prefer to use flexbox. Here is the code in your case:

```
<style>
ul.tips-and-news-posts{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.tips-and-news-posts li{
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
<style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the post in some array. The problem is to map each item in the array to one of the DIV tag.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Hyundai", "Porsche","Ferrari","Jaguar");
$len = count($cars); // Get length of array
$div = 1; // initialize div to 1

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
   if ($i%3 == 0){        // $div value would switch after 3 post. You can change this 3 to any value
      $div = ~ $div + 2 ;  // logic to convert 0 to 1 and vice versa
    }
   echo $cars[$i]." ".$div."<br>"; 
}
```